# How to stop winget from automatically installing postgres on my machine

Tags: windows, winget

Am on Windows 11. Once in a while, winget, the Windows Package manager, suddenly begins installing Postgres v14 without my consent as seen in [this screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zq2DsPfULfkh_m5hEepVFeiq0MN9QPre/view?usp=share_link). I already have Postgres 12 and do not want an automatic install of v14. How do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/package-manager/winget/) (a.k.a. WinGet) is a command line tool. It doesn't take action without a user running a command. There are several open-source utilities that leverage WinGet and one of those may have automatic processes.

I suggest looking to see if you have something else installed that is calling WinGet programmatically.

Comment: So I need to find what is initiating the installation, OK

Comment: @Peter did you find what is causing this auto installation from winget ? This is such a pain, uninstalls it and then re-installs it and dont know who is initiating it from where